# Uncoupling a coupled oscillator Hamiltonian by change of variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

I'm working on the problem of two entangled harmonic oscillators with Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{1}{2} [p_1^2 + p_2^2 + k_0(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + k_1(x_1 - x_2)^2].$$

Introducing the variables $x_± = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x_1 ± x_2)$, and frequencies $\omega_+ = k_0^{1/2}$, $\omega_- = (k_0 + 2k_1)^{1/2}$ I've tried to write this Hamiltonian in an uncoupled way.

I have found that $(x_+^2 + x_-^2) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ and $2x_-^2 = (x_1 - x_2)^2$. Furthermore, since  $ p_{1,2}^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_{1,2}^2}$ when ignoring constants, I find $$p_±^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_{1}^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_{2}^2} ± 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}.$$

Then $\frac{1}{2} (p_+^2 + p_-^2) = p_1^2 + p_2^2$.

And: $$H = \frac{1}{2} [ \frac{1}{2} (p_+^2 + p_-^2) + k_0 x_+^2 + (k_0 + 2k_1)x_-^2] = \frac{1}{2} [ \frac{1}{2} (p_+^2 + p_-^2) + \omega_+^2 x_+^2 + \omega_-^2 x_-^2]. $$

The paper I'm working from gives the normalised ground state as $$\psi_0(x_1, x_2) = \pi^{-1/2} (\omega_+ \omega_-)^{1/4} e^{-(\omega_+ x_+^2 + \omega_- x_-^2) / 2}.$$

However, when I try to check that $H \psi_0(x_1, x_2) = E \psi_0(x_1, x_2)$ I don't find anything sensible ($E$ is negative in the constant terms, and still dependent on $x_±$).

I suppose then that my Hamiltonian is wrong, but I can't find my error.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): In some of the formulas for the momenta, they should be squared, and with different sign.

Comment: You're right; I think I've fixed it now. Thanks for the edits by the way.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): In some of the formulas for the momentum squared in terms of diff. ops, they should have different sign.

Comment: Have you verified for yourself that the ground state of a single harmonic oscillator gives you $ \hat{H} \psi_0  = E_g \psi_0$ ? If so, then since your ground state wave function is the product of two wavefunctions and your Hamiltonian is the sum of two decoupled harmonic oscillators, then your desired result should follow immediately.

Comment: Qmechanic: Could you explain that? In my derivation I've used that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_±} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_±} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_±}$$, which I believe is correct in this case (then again, this would be the obvious place for an error).         
@DJBunk: I have now, and it seems to only work when I lose the extra factor half and add in a general minus sign in my final expression for the sum of momenta. My problem is that I can't seem to find the error in my derivation.

Comment: Well, I've found the minus sign: that was stupid of me. For some reason though, I keep finding $\partial x_± = \sqrt{2} [\partial x_1 + \partial x_2]$ instead of the $1/\sqrt{2}$ I need for it to work.